# How can I prevent adding duplicate classes to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I prevent adding more classes `error` while somebody is repeatedly clicking on the submit button?
In Chrome Dev Tools I see that they keep being added more and more if you spam the button. I don't know how to prevent this.

```
function errorFunc(req, message) {
    const formControl = req.parentElement;
    const span = formControl.querySelector('span');
    span.innerText = message;
    req.className += 'error';
    span.className += 'error-text';
    if(req !== email) {
        req.value = ' ';
    } else {
        req.style.color = "hsl(0, 100%, 74%)";
    }
}

function successFunc(req) {
    req.className += 'success';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `element.classList.add()` which doesn't create duplicates.

```js
const x = document.querySelector('.x');
x.classList.add('error');
console.log(x.className);
x.classList.add('error');
console.log(x.className);
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

[ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) and as the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList#trimming_of_whitespace_and_removal_of_duplicates) says:

> Methods that modify the DOMTokenList (such as DOMTokenList.add()) automatically trim any excess Whitespace and **remove duplicate values** from the list.

Answer (score 0):

can be done with simple use js internal classList of a element

```
/** @type {HTMLElement} */
let req = document.querySelector('.x');
req.classList.add('error')
```

this does not add the error class if it allready exists. and it's easier to remove the error class if not longer needed `req.classList.remove('error')` (only removes if class is present).

also you can check if the class you want to add already is existing

```
req.classList.has('error');
```

here is the manual

[HTMLElement classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)